# Reference links to algorithm but shows?

Tags: cross-referencing, algorithm2e

I am using `algorithm2e` when I reference an algorithm it shows `??` which links to the correct algorithm, but it should show something like 1.1.

Any suggestions as to how I can fix this?

Here is an mwe:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside, english]{Thesis}

\usepackage[boxed, ruled, ruled, algoruled]{./algorithm2e}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}

\ref{alg:Stage1.2} shows the algorithm.

\begin{algorithm}[!htp]
\label{alg:Stage1.2}
 \caption{Stage1.2}
\end{algorithm}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello! Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @tohecz see the updated code.

Comment: Well, put `\label` after (or inside) `\caption`, don't forget to compile twice, and you should be fine :)

Comment: @tohecz thank a lot worked like a charm :). Post is an answer.